# How can I convert URLs to base64 without outputting '/' characters?

Tags: javascript, node.js, base64, urlencode

**Question:** can I be certain that Base64 encoded URLs won't output '/' characters?

**Background:** Firebase uses a key/value structure, and its key names, [per the docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/understanding-data.html),

> "can include any unicode characters except for . $ # [ ] / and ASCII
>   control characters 0-31 and 127"

I'd like to use URLs as a key for one of my collection, but obviously the '/' and '.' make raw strings a no-go.

My plan (to which I'm not married) is to convert the URLs into Base64, using either the browser's functions (`atob()` and `btoa()`) or a dedicated function/`NPM` module ([as discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-a-string-to-base64-in-javascript)).

However, Base64 outputs can include '/', which breaks Firebase rules.

Would the characters a URL might contain ever produce a '/'?

If so, is there any reason I shouldn't just add a simple `String.replace()` to the front/back of the Base64 encoding function?

Comment: `urlencode` it. You even included this in your question's tags.

Comment: [`encodeURIComponent("my/url/here")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

Comment: oh! that's embarrassing, hah. looks like that function + a base64 converter will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Taking suggestions in OP comments (thanks ceejayoz, Derek), it looks something like this will work:

```
let rawUrl = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38679286/how-can-i-convert-urls-to-base64-without-outputting-characters?noredirect=1#comment64738129_38679286";

let key = btoa(encodeURIComponent(url)); 
let decodedUrl = decodeURIComponent(atob(key));

rawUrl == decodedUrl // True
```

Comment: This may throw `URIError: malformed URI sequence` for some characters. And I think the output can still have `/`.

Answer (score 0):

You can always just replace those characters after base64 encoding them, and then replace again when decoding.

```
const fireBase64 = {
  encode: (str) => btoa(str).replace(/\//g, '_'),
  decode: (b64) => atob(b64.replace(/_/g, '/'))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The possible characters in a base64 string are

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/
```

If you don't want `/`, just replace it with another character not present in the list above, e.g. `_`.

```js
var string = "ü";
var encoded = btoa(string).replace(/\//g, '_'); 
var decoded = atob(encoded.replace(/_/g, '/'));

console.log(btoa(string).indexOf('/') > -1); // true :(
console.log(encoded.indexOf('/') > -1); // false :)
console.log(string == decoded); // true :)
```